# Finding real cubic root of the equation

Tags: linear-algebra, roots

The cubic equation has one real root.Find it.
$\displaystyle 8x^3-3x^2-3x-1=0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HINT:

We have $$9x^3=(x+1)^3\iff \left(1+\frac1x\right)^3=9$$

Observe that $x$ will be real or complex according as $\displaystyle 1+\frac1x $

Comment: You really enjoy (x + 1 / x) ! This leads, when feasible, to wonderful solutions. Cheers.

Comment: I think that should be $\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^3 = 9$.

Comment: @peterwhy, definitely, I couldn't rectify as I was on my way home. Thanks

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, wish you'd verified the mistake:)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee. Nooooo ! I was so impressed that I did not pay attention to that.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, please don't mind. I was just joking